# Error while using Apache CXF Codegen Plugin in pom.xml.Error in execution tag while trying to update the maven. How to resolve this?

Tags: plugins, cxf, pom.xml

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/CustomerOrders.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <wsdlLocation>classpath:CustomerOrders.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

I am trying to generate stubs from the WSDL file using Apache CXF-Codegen plugin.
Error in execution tag while trying to update the maven.Tried enclosing the plugin in pluginManagement tag but no result whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `wsdlLocation`, it's enough to configure `wsdl`.

See also https://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html or sources https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/maven-plugins/codegen-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/maven_plugin/wsdl2java/WsdlOption.java